# java read file ---- Why my code works

Tags: java, file-io

I am new in Java. I am learning the fileIO. I was writing a little program to display the content in a txt file. My code is as follow :

```
import java.io.*;

public class Readf {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
            FileInputStream in = null ;
            try {
                    in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
                    int c;
                    String cs="";
                    while ((c=in.read())!=-1) {
                            cs = cs + (char)c;
                            if ((char)c=='\n') {
                                    System.out.println(cs);
                                    cs="";
                            }
                    }

            } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                            in.close();
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I was reading an online tutorial. It told me to read the file with an int variable. Since I wanted to display the content in char, I cast them into char type and store it into a sting and it WORKED!!!! In Java, a int variable is 32-bit but a char variable is 16-bit. I cast them into 16bit char every time I read an 32bit int. Why the result wasn't a chaos?

Comment: If you want chaos, use characters outside the BMP in your input file, e.g: 

Comment: Actually, anything that is not ASCII would be a good counter example. Try a file that has something like `é` or `ç`. Or something in Arabic, Chinese etc., like 猫

Answer (score 1):

Check read() method description in FileInputStream class:

[FileInputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read())

As you can see in specification, a read method "Reads **a byte** of data from this input stream" which means all your ints in your program (c variable) will always be less than or equal to 255 and greater that or equal to 0. It doesn't matter if you read txt file or pdf, png etc.

You can check it by trying to print something when c is greater than 255, eg.:

```
if (c > 255) {
    System.out.println("c>255");
}
```

and "c>255" will never be printed.

Because int is signed you can also check if c is less than zero.

```
if (c < 0) {
    System.out.println("c<0");
}
```

and again "c<0" will never be printed as well.

Only last int will be -1 of course.

So every int from a range <0, 255> can be safely cast to char without loosing any information.

Comment: check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I think the **byte** will be between -128 and +127 (included) not 255 unless it is unsigned ..

Comment: Yes, byte in Java is signed and is from range <-128, 127>.In the javadoc of read() method there is "a byte of data" which I understand as "8 bits of data" and it doesn't have to be Java byte primitive type. I think that's why read() method doesn't return byte but int.

Comment: This is almost correct. The value is going to be 0-255 if a byte was actually read. But -1 is a legitimate value, indicating end of file. That's why it's the condition of the loop. And that's also why the return value is int rather than byte: it needs to be able to return 257 possible values, and byte only allows 256.

Answer (score 0):

All the characters you will possibly keep in your file will be well within the range of 16 bit unicode character set which java works upon. Hence there should not be any problem converting a char(16 bit) to an int(32 bit) or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I respect your insistence to understand rather than to just get the desired output.

The catch is that each character you scan has an ascii value below 2^8 which makes it fits in `int`32-bit and fits in `char`16-bit.
The chaos you are taking about will appear in the case an ascii value fits in 32-bit but not in 16-bit which will not exist in ascii character set but in  unicode.

[check the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com)